# In PHP, how can I tell what values are adjacent to a specific value in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values.  Let's say the array is like this:

```
[apple, banana, coconut, duku, emblica, fig, gooseberry]
```

Let's say that I know a specific value, "fig."  How can I know which values are next to it, both before and after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$index = array_search("fig", $array);
$before = "";
$after = "";
if($index === false){
    echo "Not found";
}else{
    $before = $index > 0 ? $array[$index - 1] : "";
    $after = ($index + 1) < count($array) ? $array[$index + 1] : "";
}
```

Comment: This solution seems the most intuitive to me, and handles the starting and ending values pretty well.

But...I do not understand what the ? : syntax is, and I can't figure it out trying to read the PHP manual.  Just a hint will help, please! :)

Comment: @Jerry Rowe: It's called the ternary operator, you can read about it here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation    

It's very similar to an if / else statement

Comment: What about arrays that have missing elements? You can still get an out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: That is actually an amazingly good question, Jay---I'm glad you put your answer down below, too, because I will surely come to reference this again at some point!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the keys are sequential:

```
$key = array_search($fruit, 'fig');
if ($key === FALSE) {
    echo 'No figs in array';
} else {
    echo "Before: ", $fruit[$key-1];
    echo "After: ", $fruit[$key+1];
}
```

Comment: What happens if fig is the first or last index?

Answer (score 1):

You would use

```
$key = array_search($array); 
$leftVal = $array[$key - 1];
$rightVal = $array[$key + 1];
```

The array_search() function returns the index of the value in the array, and then just increment/de-increment to find adjacent values.

Comment: Note: This needs a check for array bounds. Trying to access an array key that doesn't exist will trigger a Notice if you have your error reporting turned up.

Comment: This was handy because it broke it down to the most primary thing I needed to understand.  +1 for you!

Comment: Cheers, yeah I was going for the most basic implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is almost correct, but it does not handle "missing" elements so well.

You can use the function array_key_exists() to validate whether a key exists, and this also works as a bounds check.

Try this:

```
<?php

function array_before_after($stext,$array) {
$index = array_search($stext, $array);
$before = "";
$after = "";
    if($index === false){
        echo "Not found";
    }else{
        $before = array_key_exists($index - 1,$array) ? $array[$index - 1] : "";
        $after = array_key_exists($index + 1,$array) ? $array[$index + 1] : "";
    }
    return array($before,$after);
}

$my_array = array( 1 => "apple", 2 => "banana", 3 => "coconut", 6 => "fig", 7 => "gooseberry");

$my_stext = "fig";
$a1 = array_before_after($my_stext, $my_array);
echo "'$a1[0]', '$my_stext', '$a1[1]'\n";

$my_stext = "apple";
$a2 = array_before_after($my_stext, $my_array);
echo "'$a2[0]', '$my_stext', '$a2[1]'\n";

$my_stext = "gooseberry";
$a3 = array_before_after($my_stext, $my_array);
echo "'$a3[0]', '$my_stext', '$a3[1]'\n";

?>
```

If you want the preceding value, you can use ***reset()*** and ***next()***:

```
<?php

function array_before_after($stext,$array) {
    $my_array = $array;
    $val = reset($my_array);
    $before = "";
    $after="";
    $lim = count($my_array);
    for ($i=1; $i<$lim; $i++) {
        if ($val == $stext) {
            if ( $i<$lim ) $after=next($my_array);
            break;
        } else {
            $before = $val;
        }
        $val = next($my_array);
    }
    return array($before,$after);
}

$my_array = array( 1 => "apple", 2 => "banana", 3 => "coconut", 6 => "fig", 7 => "gooseberry");

$my_stext = "fig";
$a1 = array_before_after($my_stext, $my_array);
echo "'$a1[0]', '$my_stext', '$a1[1]'\n";

$my_stext = "apple";
$a2 = array_before_after($my_stext, $my_array);
echo "'$a2[0]', '$my_stext', '$a2[1]'\n";

$my_stext = "gooseberry";
$a3 = array_before_after($my_stext, $my_array);
echo "'$a3[0]', '$my_stext', '$a3[1]'\n";

?>
```

Comment: That's only necessary if he is using an associative array that isn't contiguously indexed.  From his example, that is not the case.

Comment: @GWW, Agreed, but using array_key_exists() works for both cases.

Comment: @Jay Elston: Not exactly, if the adjacent entry is more than 1 away your code doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @GWW -- that depends on what the expected behavior is when there are gaps in the array -- should the gap be returned, or do you skip the gaps? If [3] is "coconut", and [4] and [5] are missing, do you want [5] (which is missing, so return a ""), or [3]?

Comment: Wow, ok, this is pretty interesting!  GWW's method was all I really needed, as it isn't possible for there to be gaps with what I am doing.  But seeing you two go back and forth was REALLY informative!  Jay, thanks a ton for making this more clear, because it addresses an issue I hadn't even considered, but surely one day will in some other context!  And this is exactly why I <3 Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Jerry: thanks :-) I actually do not know that much php, I answered this as an exercise in understanding php arrays. They are an interesting combination of ordered lists and hashmaps. Assumptions made about some of the concepts (adjacency, in this case) that you form when you learn one programming language can cause you grief when you use another language where those assumptions are false. That is why I spend time RTFM...

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'duku', 'emblica', 'fig', 'gooseberry'];

echo $my_array[ 5 ]; // Will print fig
echo $my_array[ 4 ]; // Will print emblica
echo $my_array[ 6 ]; // Will print gooseberry
```

Comment: And how does one figure out that, given 'fig', we should look at 5,4,6? This is useless for the OP's purposes. He needs to know what index 'fig' is at to be able to caculate the +1/-1 positions.